# The same code works using HttpWebRequest but not using HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, httprequest, httpclient

I've created `HttpClient` that I'm using for sending requests:

```
public static void Initialize()
{
    handler = new HttpClientHandler() { UseCookies = false, AllowAutoRedirect = true };
    http = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://csgolounge.com/mytrades") };
    http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36");
}
```

After that I'm creating instance of custom class that stores the cookies string for an account (something like `id=xxxxxxxx; tkz=xxxxxxxxxx; token=xxxxxxxxxxx`.

That's how I'm sending a post request:

```
public async Task Bump()
{
    //if (Bumpable)
    //{
    var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://www.csgolounge.com/ajax/bumpTrade.php");
    req.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieString);
    req.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    req.Headers.Add("Referer", "http://csgolounge.com/mytrades"); //Not really sure if this does anything but I've run out of smart ideas long time ago

    /*Dictionary<string, string> postData = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"trade", offer_id}
    };
    var encoded = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
    */
    req.Content = new StringContent("&trade="+Offer_id, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); //Desperation.. decided to change the encoded dictionary to StringContent
    var res = await SteamAccount.http.SendAsync(req);
    var html = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    //}
}
```

I don't get what's wrong with this code. It seems correct to me.

Also, when I set `AllowAutoRedirect = false` it returns 301: Moved Permanently error, while normally it returns 200 with no HTML no matter what I pass as content.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Here's the `JavaScript` function I'm basing my request on:

```
function bumpTrade(trade) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/bumpTrade.php",
        data: "trade=" + trade
    });
}
```

I've worked with more complex AJAX before, but this just doesn't seem to work no matter what I do.

Edit: I've lost my patience and switched to `HttpWebRequest` instead.

Now the method looks like this:

```
public async Task BumpLegacy()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://csgolounge.com/ajax/bumpTrade.php");
            var cc = new CookieContainer();
            MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(Account.CookieString, @"\s?([^=]+)=([^;]+);");
            foreach (Match m in mc)
                cc.Add(new Cookie(m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value, "/", "csgolounge.com"));
            httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cc;
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("trade=" + Offer_id);
            httpWebRequest.Referer = "http://csgolounge.com/mytrades";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
            httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36";
            httpWebRequest.ContentLength = (long)bytes.Length;
            var g = await httpWebRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync();
            await g.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Count());
            g.Close();
            var res = await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();
            res.Close();
            break;
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe I'm just dumb but for me it doesn't seem all that different. Are there some key differences that can be the cause?

Comment: Didn't notice that, thanks for pointing it out, your majesty.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: Even though I get status code 200 nothing happens. Also, there is no message that my request lacks some parameter or something similar. Everything seems to work in theory, yet it doesn't.

Comment: Have you been able to confirm through an HTTP proxy outside of your code that a /POST to the resource you have identified will produce the results you desire?  Go to Fiddler and compose a `/POST` to see if the resource system is integrating your request properly; otherwise, you have too many variables under test at the same time.

Comment: I have switched to `HttpWebRequest` instead, because I knew that it worked for sure with this but I still can't understand why. What exactly am I doing differently here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code from one of my working systems that submits a POST request through an `HTTPClient`.

```
[Route("resource")]
public async Task<dynamic> CreateResource([FromBody]Resource resource)
{
    if (resource == null) return BadRequest();
    dynamic response = null;
    resource.Topic = GetDataFromSomewhereElse();
    var message = new PostMessage(resource).BodyContent;

    dynamic postRequest = new
    {
        Message = message
    };
    var post = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postRequest);

    HttpContent content = new StringContent(post, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        try
        {
            client.BaseAddress = @"http://localhost:51145/"; 

            HttpResponseMessage postResponse = await client.PostAsync("Resource", content); //"Resource" is a route exposed on the remote host

            string json = await postResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (postResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) return BadRequest();
            if (postResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) return InternalServerError();
            if (postResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound) return NotFound();

            return json;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

[Edit]
The "PostMessage" was modified to remove domain-specific details.  Here is how `BodyContent` is defined inside the real "PostMessage" from my solution, to provide you enough context to understand what that "message" actually is and how it works into the sample.

```
public string BodyContent
    {
        get
        {
            string content = "";

            Type type = this.GetType();
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string resource = String.Format("{0}.{1}", type.Namespace, this.EmbeddedResourceName);
            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            content = reader.ReadToEnd();

            return content;
        }
    }
```

...and here is `PostRequest` (again, with domain-specific details trimmed)

```
public class PostRequest
{
   public string Message { get;set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't think result is any different with this method

Comment: @Reynevan Then the issue is either with the remote service host or with your calling convention.  If you're required to structure your POST body a certain way, then its possible that their service endpoint is rejecting it but responding with a 200 OK (silly) My suggestion is to first remove the C# http client libraries from the equation.  Go into either Fiddler or POSTman and send that server a POST request.  Then go confirm (however it is that you do that with the remote server) that your POST was processed. Then add in the automated client code.

Comment: I did almost exactly like you say, turns out the response looks the same whether the request failed or succeeded. I checked how exactly it looks with Fiddler and assigned missing headers. Seems to have helped. Thanks for info.